# akka-http how to accept invalid URI [will not solve]

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am developing a service that is called on one path with different query parameters. I have bind a Route to Http:

```
val route: Route = {
    get {
        pathPrefix("myRoute"){
            parameterMap{ params =>
                complete(
                   MyHandler.genExternResponse(params)
                )
            }
        }
    }

val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandleAsync(Route.asyncHandler(new myEndpoint().route), "localhost", 8081)
```

Since i have no influence on what parameters are used, i can't eliminate the calls that contain not-encoded special chars like German umlauts or trademark signs. 
for example

```
www.myhost.com/myRoute?param1=asd&param2=adäöü
```

I know that those URLs are not valid But one of the requirements is that even requests with those chars are accepted und that i handle them with URL encoding.
The problem is that when i call the service like above, akka-http rejects the request with the Response-status 400 without even handing it to my code.
Is there a way that i can catch those request and handle them by myself or let akka-http URL-encode the special chars for me.

edit:
will not solve

Comment: could you post a stacktrace?

Comment: don't know how since there is no error in code that prints a stacktrace and akka-http is just responding with 400.

Comment: Could it be `MyHandler.genExternResponse` which is throwing an exception? Exceptions thrown here will convert to a 400. If you change your code to a complete ("ok") you don't get the error, so it's unlikely to be Akka's fault

Comment: no the problem is, that the request never even reaches my endpoint. even if i use the most basic examples from the akka-http dokumentation it wont except uri parameters with umlauts

Comment: uhmm weird it did work fine when I tried with `complete("ok")`

Comment: did you make a request with an parameter like ?param1=abäüß?

Comment: Yes same request query as in your question

Comment: could you please send me the code you tried it witch and the build.sbt in a pm? because on my service the response is always a 400 with the entity:
Illegal request-target: Invalid input 'Ã', expected raw-query-char or 'EOI' (line 1, column 13)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 val route: Route = {
  get {
    pathPrefix("myRoute"){
        parameters('params)
           { params =>
            complete(
               MyHandler.genExternResponse(params)
            )
        }
    }
}

val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandleAsync(Route.asyncHandler(new myEndpoint().route), "localhost", 8081)
```

Comment: sadly that didn't work :
~ curl -i http://localhost:8080/myRoute\?page\=täst 
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: akka-http/10.0.3
Date: Tue, 31 Jan 2017 10:10:18 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 96

Illegal request-target: Invalid input 'Ã', expected raw-query-char or 'EOI' (line 1, column 13)%

Comment: Change the parameter name                                                                  curl -i localhost:8080/myRoute?params=täst

Comment: did that too the request doesn't reach my endpoint. I think akka-http can't create a HttpRequest from the connection in normal configuration because it contains an non-7bit-ASCII character

Comment: You are hitting wrong route curl -i localhost:8080/myRoute\?page\=täst you shoud hit like this curl -i localhost:8080/myRoute?params=täst

Comment: aren't the \ necessary to escape the '?' ?
if i do the same curl but with \?page\=test instead of täst it works fine and i can use the parameter